# Qt 4.8 killing and restarting the GUI

Tags: qt, qt4

There is requirement of writing a Qt application on a MIPS based platform.

But there are lots of constraints. The constraints included freeing up of few resources (QGFX Plugin, GPU Memory etc) when required and re-using it. But the application cannot be killed as its handling lots of other requests and running other things.

Basically the GUI needs to be killed and free all the resources related to GUI; later when when required restart again

One of the way which has been tried is :

main() -> create a New-Thread

In the New-Thread,

```
while(<Condition>)
{
  sem_wait(..)
  m_wnd =  new myMainWindow();
   ...
   ..
   app->exec();
}
```

When ever there is a kill command, it comes out of the event loop, and wait for the signal from other threads. Once other threads does the required changes, it will get the signal and will create a new window and goes into the event loop.

In the main(), there are also few other threads created, which control other devices etc and signal the start and stop for the Qt-GUI.

The above seems to work but I am not sure if this is the right design. Does it create any problem?

Can any one suggest any better way?

Comment: I would suggest that when running on a system with very constrained memory, Qt should probably not be used.

Comment: Even though we have memory, there is some constraint, how we use it (Especially GPU memory, blitters, GPUs). When some other application wants to use it, due to its singularity-device mode, Qt has to release these .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the required answer in Qt-Forums.

Since the main intention was to remove all the things related to GUI (On screen), I could use `void setQuitOnLastWindowClosed ( bool quit )` [(Details Here)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop). This will make sure the GUI / Main window is closed and still the app doesnt come out of event loop and I can restart the main window later.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I needed a way to ensure that my app kept running, I forked it into a sub-process. That way, even if it seg-faulted, the main process would catch it and start a new child process. In the child process, I had multiple threads for GUI and non-GUI tasks. The fork code is short and is based on the example given in the [wait(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) man page. The main() simply calls `createChild()` in a while loop. `createChild()` starts a new process using `zmain()`. `zmain()` is your QT app's main.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QThread>

int zmain(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv, true);
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);

    QThread powerThread;
    Power p;
    p.moveToThread(&powerThread);
    powerThread.start();

    return app.exec();
}

// The following code is taken from the wait(2) man page and has been modified to run
// our Qt main() above in a child process. When the child terminates, it is automatically
// restarted.

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int createChild(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t cpid, w;
    int status;

    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (cpid == 0) {            /* Code executed by child */
        fprintf(stderr, "Child PID is %ld\n", (long) getpid());
        exit(zmain(argc, argv));
    } else {                    /* Code executed by parent */
        do {
            w = waitpid(cpid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
            if (w == -1) {
                perror("waitpid");
                return(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
            } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
            } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "continued\n");
            }
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
        if (WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == 111)
            return 111;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (111 != createChild(argc, argv)) {
    }
}
```